# Running code inside void loop() vs inside a separate function with an infinite loop in it

Tags: esp8266, stepper

I'm writing a program for running a stepper motor at a high RPM using accelStepper on a NodeMCU esp8266. Super New to the accelStepper but reading, experimenting and learning as I go

When the code to cycle the stepper one way and then the other is inside the `void loop()` it works as expected, but there's a bunch of other inputs I need to check in there for setting up the system and when they are all inside the `void loop()` they slow down the cycle noticeably as it does various digital and analog reads.

While the stepper is cycling I only really need to watch one e-stop input instead of everything so I figured to create a separate function with an infinite loop in it, call the stepper code there and just check the one input and return out of the function when done

Testing this and it partially works but the stepper only makes it part way to its end point and then abruptly stops (instead of decelerating) and then reverse and same thing.

Probably not even the right way of trying to solve my issue but it's what I came up with tonight.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the **entire** test code I'm using. When I un-comment the block of code inside the `void loop()` and comment out the call to the go_to function it works perfectly fine. When that basically exact same block of code is run inside the go_to instead, it gives the weird results

```cpp
    #include <AccelStepper.h>
    
    const int DIR = D6;
    const int STEP = D7; 
    
    AccelStepper stepper(1,STEP,DIR); 
    
    int EndPoint = 50000
    
    
    void setup()
    {  
      stepper.setMaxSpeed(8000); 
      stepper.setAcceleration(10000);   
      stepper.setMinPulseWidth(10);     
      stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);     
      delay(2000);  // need to prevent partial run when loading
    }
    
    
    void loop()
    {
      /*  if this code runs it works perfectly
      stepper.run(); 
      if (stepper.currentPosition()==EndPoint)
        {
        NewEndPoint=0;
        stepper.moveTo(NewEndPoint);
        }
      else if (stepper.currentPosition()==0)
        {
        NewEndPoint=EndPoint;
        stepper.moveTo(NewEndPoint);
        }
        */
    
      go_to();
      
    }
    
    
    void go_to()
    {
      for(;;) // have tried while(true) also, same results
      {
      stepper.run();
      if (stepper.currentPosition()==EndPoint)
        {
        NewEndPoint=0;
        stepper.moveTo(NewEndPoint);
        }
      else if (stepper.currentPosition()==0)
        {
        NewEndPoint=EndPoint;
        stepper.moveTo(NewEndPoint);
        }
      }
    }
```

The reason I'm trying to get this to work is for the full program, there's several digital and analog reads than need to be done for speed, distance, number of cycles etc. that all must be in the `void loop()`, or called from there, and if they are in the same loop where the `stepper.run()` is it slows the RPM down a lot so I'm trying to get the `stepper.run()` into it's own loop where it's not looking at any inputs it doesn't need to but I ran into this problem and don't see why it's reacting the way it is.

Comment: both of the codes do the same thing ... the second code never exits back to loop()

Comment: They were supposed to do the same thing. It's the exact same code but when it's inside the separate function the stepper only goes part way towards the endpoint and then stops hard, delays a bit and then starts the reverse direction, goes part way and stops hard, then repeats. I never bothered adding the way out of the function since it's not working the way I expected.

Comment: there may be some housekeeping done at each iteration of `loop()` ... the loop inside `go_to()` prevents it from executing

Comment: If the stepper motor code has to be serviced quickly then you have to focus on the other code that you have removed from the loop() for this demonstration and which slowed it down. You must eliminate any blocking code such as delay() or complex float or other time intensive calculations. An alternative is maybe to move to the ESP32 platform where you can use RTOS to run fast and slow code more or less in parallel.

Comment: look at the `random` example sketch in the accelStepper library ... use `distanceToGo` instead of `currentPosition` for simpler code

Comment: Your problem lies in a part of your code that you have removed. Please, post a complete, testable (and tested!) example.

Comment: I've added the complete code that I'm testing, it's only the setup that is missing. This is the actual code I'm testing that works inside the void loop but only moves the steppers part way if run inside the separate function.

Comment: Can you try this on an AVR-based micro, an Uno or a Mega? My expectation is that you will see the motor run as expected, whether executing within `loop()` or within `go_to()`.<br>On an ESP8266, a lot more happens between calls to `loop()` than does on AVRs. It seems likely that some one or more of these background tasks on the ESP between calls to `loop()` is necessary for your motor code to execute properly. But when you run the motor in `go_to()` on an ESP, `loop()` never returns and those background tasks don't get done.

Comment: I can wire it and try on a mega tonight and see if that works. What you're saying about the background tasks between loop calls being missing makes a certain amount of sense. Will post back results

Comment: Or, an even simpler test, possibly even a fix: still using the ESP: just add a call to `yield()` inside the `for(;;){}` loop at the top or bottom of it. `yield()` is designed specifically to allow long-running processes such as yours to give the background an opportunity to do its necessary chores, at a point of the programmer's choosing.

Comment: So the original problem of the steppers acting differently inside a different function than the loop() certainly seems to be because of the "additional code that needs to run between iterations of the loop function", "On an ESP8266, a lot more happens between calls to loop() than does on AVRs" that was pointed out. Adding a yield() to the separate function fixed the stepper issue... I'll say that this problem is solved. Unfortunately it also brought up a different problem with my process so back to the drawing board.
Thanks so much for the insight and suggestions, I'm going to go and try some

Answer (score 1):

`loop` already runs indefinitely, hence its name. You don't need to add another loop in your `go_to` function. Remove that and it should be functionally identical.

Answer (score 1):

The ESP8266 has additional code that needs to run between iterations of the loop function.  If you are going to trap it elsewhere in some while loop, then you need to also be sure to call `delay(0);` or `yield;` in there so that it can handle its other business.  If the code around loop doesn't get run in time, then the board resets from the watchdog IIRC.  I believe that is the symptom you are seeing.

And like the others say, there is no good reason for a blocking loop in your code.  Let the loop function be the loop.

Comment: I'd like to have it in the main loop but I haven't figured out how to prevent the digital and analog reads that have to happen in there from slowing this run() down. Bad enough I'm still going to have to have a single digitalRead of the e-stop switch happen with this run(). Maybe using a interrupt (attachInterrupt()? ) would be a better option than the digitalRead().

Comment: Put those reads in an if statement so they only run when the other part isn't.  You're not running anything concurrently, so however you have it structured now you could just move the function back into loop.

Comment: No, an interrupt will just make it more complicated.  You need a boolean variable that tells which part should be happening and then a couple of if statements in loop to decide if loop is reading inputs or running steppers.  Really it should be able to do both.  There's really no reason that the stepper code needs to be blocking.  But for some reason everyone is reluctant to try to learn non-blocking techniques.

Comment: Adding the yield() to the end of the go_to() function resolved the weird behaviour of the stepper motors and now they act the same as they did when running the code within the loop(). BUT it's not treating the function as something that needs to be completed before returning to the main loop.... I've got some more reading to do on that command I guess. But it answers the question of why the test code wasn't working.

Comment: You shouldn't code it to need to be complete before returning to the main loop.  That is a poor blocking design.  Code it like a state machine so the loop can still run while the steppers are moving.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix all of this is going to be to keep your stepper code within the loop function, but keep a variable that "remembers" when the stepper is running. Use that variable to know when not to do the time-consuming tasks. Let `loop()` return after each iteration whether the stepper is running or not. No `yield()` call will be needed. Just make sure to know when the stepper is running and don't do the long jobs if when is.

Perhaps something like this (untried!) code-structure:

```
void loop()
{
   static bool isStepping = false;
     :
   if( !isStepping ){
      /* call time-consuming tasks here; */

      if( time to start the stepper now ){
         /* set up any stepping conditions you need to here; */
         isStepping = true;
   }
 
   if( isStepping ){
      /* run one iteration of the stepper code; */
      if( stepping is complete ){
         isStepping = false;
      }
   }
}  // let your loop() return after each stepper iteration
```

Comment: I'll have to try some of these other approaches since the separate loop doesn't seem to work the way I was hoping, the yield did work to fix the stepper stopping but it created a different problem in the sub-function so I'm going to re-read all of these answers and suggestions and try a different approach.